# Haskell type signature

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble understanding this type signature:

```
config :: Config Snap ()
config = setPort 8888 defaultConfig
```

Where are the `->` stating the params and return type of the function? What am I missing here?

Comment: setPort :: Int -> Config m a -> Config m a ; defaultConfig :: MonadSnap m => Config m a

Answer (score 4):

The `->` infix type constructor takes an argument type on the left and a result type on the right. `config` has no parameters, and it makes no sense to write `->` with nothing on the left, so the result type is the only type.

You can do the same thing with types you're more familiar with. For example:

```
example1 :: Int
example1 = 1

example2 :: Maybe Integer
example2 = Just 2

example3 :: [Double]
example3 = [1,2,3]

example4 :: Either String Int
example4 = Right 4
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a function here - it's a value (well it's the configuration for snap): a [Snap `Config`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/Snap-Http-Server-Config.html#t:Config) with the [`Snap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.7.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#t:Snap) monad and *empty* `()` additional (`other`) information sitting on it.

As you can read in the documentation it's more or less a starting point and you use the [functions here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.5.1/docs/Snap-Http-Server-Config.html) to set additional informations.

So in a sense it's just the same as writing

```
myInt :: Int
myInt = 4
```

Comment: Although `()` is used in monadic code as a placeholder to mean "nothing of interest", it's better known as *unit* than *empty*, which is more accurate because it has exactly one value (not none, as empty might indicate).

Comment: yeah of course - but in this case I think it's ok to assume that it was meant to just say there is *nothing of interest*  for `other` don't you think? (that's why I put it in cursive)

Comment: Agreed. I just pointed out the name of `()` because the OP seems to be an early beginner and may not know what people mean who read that signature aloud and pronounce it unit.